# How do I incrementally increase animation delay with vanilla JS for each post on in a wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, css-animations

I have a php loop to show posts on a archive category page of a wordpress theme.  I have also created an animation that takes the post from opacity=o to opacity=1 in .2s. I want to increase the delay of the animation for each additional post so the first post in the list appears a few milliseconds before the next post. I have already accomplished this using :nth-of-type(n) for a max post limit of 15.  I know this is highly ineffective and would like to use (a loop?) JavaScript to handle animation delay with an incremental time increase.

```
@keyframes fade-in {
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
     }
}
#section-grid a:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation: fade-in .2s 0s forwards ease-out;
}

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
         <div>
            <img src="<?php the_field('feature_image2'); ?>" alt="plant">
               <aside>
                   <?php the_title(); ?>
               </aside>
         </div>
      </a>

      <?php endwhile; else: ?>
          <div class="page-header">
               <h1>Coming Soon</h1>
          </div>
          <p>If there is nothing here that doesn't mean nothing is coming. Stay tuned for updates and new information.</p>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

I would like for the animation delay to increase by .05s for each new post on an archive page. I would then be able to remove the :nth-of-type from my CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inline css this way (the delay here is in milliseconds):

```html
#section-grid a:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation: fade-in .2s 0s forwards ease-out;
}

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$last_anim=0;
?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="animation:fade-in .2s .<?php echo $last_anim; ?>ms forwards ease-out;">
         <div>
            <img src="<?php the_field('feature_image2'); ?>" alt="plant">
               <aside>
                   <?php the_title();
                   $last_anim+=500;
                   ?>
               </aside>
         </div>
      </a>

      <?php endwhile; else: ?>
          <div class="page-header">
               <h1>Coming Soon</h1>
          </div>
          <p>If there is nothing here that doesn't mean nothing is coming. Stay tuned for updates and new information.</p>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a JavaScript library for this.

https://greensock.com/docs/TimelineMax/staggerTo

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.js-animate');

TweenMax.staggerTo(elements, 0.2, {
    autoAlpha: 1
}, 0.1);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qgkah26v/3/